# Dynamically accessing a dataframe from a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

All, I'm trying to access data frames from the content of a variable, so the process can be automated in R.

Let's say I have 10 data frames with unordered names, containing item numbers. I'm trying to merge these data frames one by one with a purchase record, matched by the item primary key. This is a straightforward challenge for one or few data frames, with a larger number, but it's really cumbersome for a large number of dataframes.

```
dfs <- c("Chocolate", "Gum", "Cookies", "PotatoChips", "HotSauce", "Bread", "Yogurt", "Shampoo", "BodyWash", "ShoePolish")
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
   assign(paste("trx_",dfs[i],sep=""), merge(get(dfs[i]),trx,by="item_no")) }
```

So, I want to automatically create data frames, e.g. trx_Chocolate, trx_Gum, containing the merged records rather than doing it one by one. The issue is with the merge as it produces an error message about me not having a valid column name - presumably due to dynamically addressing the data frames through the content of a list variable.

I know that there's a possible solution as well in storing the data frames as .CSV, and then reading them one by one back again and merge the data frames that way. However, I'm trying not to create excessive intermediary files if I can help it.

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add the specific error you receive? If you receive `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column` or similar, it is probably because you don't have the column `item_no` in both the data frames you are trying to merge.

Comment: You should never "have 10 data frames with unordered names" that are conceptually related (e.g., you want to loop over them). They should be together in one object (most easy case, simply put them in one list when you create them). And, please, forget that `assign` exists. If you need it, you are doing something wrong (or something very advanced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trying to answer your question, I created a reproducible example. (In the future, I would recommend you include a reprex.)

Your code actually appears to work just fine. See the example below.

As a next step, I would confirm that each of the data.frames whose names are in the vector `df` actually have the column "item_no." Also confirm `trx` has this column. Otherwise, this error does not make sense.

I would also encourage you to explore options where you do not create different data.frames in the first place. Dynamically referencing/assigning data.frames can cause unexpected challenges -- and makes your code less readable.

You can potentially keep everything in the same, long data.frame and subset out just the items that you need when automating the process. At first glance, this might seem tricky but if possible it might well simplify a lot of the issues you are encountering.

If you need additional assistance please consider posting a reproducible example that further illustrates the issues you are having.

```
dfs <- c("Chocolate", "Gum", "Cookies", "PotatoChips", "HotSauce", "Bread", "Yogurt", "Shampoo", "BodyWash", "ShoePolish")
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
   assign(paste("trx_",dfs[i],sep=""), merge(get(dfs[i]),trx,by="item_no")) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ryan! I had the 'Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column' error before, but it seems to have solved itself now. Thank you for your advice too. 

I thought I'd leave the question here, in case there are others who may have a similar challenge in the future. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a reproducible example, and your code works fine.

First create some dummy data:

```
trx <- data.frame('item_no' = paste0('item_',1:10))
Chocolate <- data.frame('item_no' = paste0('item_',1:5), 'col1' = 1:5)
Cookies <- data.frame('item_no' = paste0('item_',5:7), 'col1' = 1)
```

Run your code:

```
dfs <- c('Chocolate', 'Cookies')
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
  assign(paste0('trx_',dfs[i]), merge(get(dfs[i]), trx, by="item_no")) }
```

View output:

```
> trx_Chocolate
  item_no col1
1  item_1    1
2  item_2    2
3  item_3    3
4  item_4    4
5  item_5    5
> trx_Cookies
  item_no col1
1  item_5    1
2  item_6    1
3  item_7    1
```

If you do not have `item_no` in both the data frames you are trying to merge, you will receive the error: `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, cddt -- a fantastic testament to the wonderful stackoverflow community! I had the 'Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column' error before, but it seems to have solved itself now.